Highlight words found with the local Vuetify Datatable search (filter) function
I am planning to use the Vuetify v3 DataTable component to show the contents of a relatively small array of objects, therefore its local filter/search functionality works perfectly for me. However, each object in this array contains a property with a lot of text in it. When I search for a word and the DataTable component filters out only the rows containing the word in all columns/properties, I can't see exactly where the word was found - so I would like to highlight all matched words with the yellow background. Is it possible at all and if yes - how?
The official documentation and its examples doesn't mention any possibility to highlight the search results. I suspect this might be made possible through implementing my own custom filter, but I think this is a pretty usual feature so I hope there is an easier way.
